# $P \oplus A^m\cong A^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-k-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit and $P$ an $A$-module, I know that if $A^n\cong A^m\implies n=m$, then this number $n$ is well defined. I would like to prove that if $P\oplus A^m\cong A^n$, this number $n-m$ is well defined also. I'm trying to use the fact I've said above to prove this, am I on the right way? What is the standard proof of this fact?

Thanks

Comment: What is $P$? What is $A$?

Comment: @Brad I'm sorry, is it ok now?

Comment: I think you want $A$ to be commutative.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff yes

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be a prime ideal and define a functor $F_p(M)=M\otimes A_p/p$, and let $r_p(M)=\dim F_p(M)$. Then $n-m=r_p(P)$.  So not only is the difference well defined, but there is a rank which can by computed at any prime ideal for arbitrary finitely generated projective modules (and not just stably free ones).

Comment: Note, rank may depend on $p$ in the non-stably-free case. Also, since quootienting is not exact, rank need not be additive for all short exact sequences. It is additive over split sequences, though.